# strange characters (@) in .dtb files in /boot/overlays/

Tags: boot

If I open the dtb files in `/boot/overlays` either with `nano` or `vi` I do see strange characters in the files:
`^@^@^A^G^@^@^@8^@^@^@ ^@^@^@(^@^@^@^Q^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@'^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@brcm,bcm2708^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Afragment@0^@`

Any idea what is happening ? I do access the files via ssh

Comment: Aren't the .dtb files binary (contrary to dts) ? Binary files will  seem to contain garbage if opened with a text editor - you can try this with notepad on Windows too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .dtb are the compiled versions of the text files.  They are not intended to be read.

You will need to find the corresponding .dts files.

Look for the .dts files on github under https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.1.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert the binary device tree file (`.dtb`) into a device tree source file (`.dts`). You can use a [device tree compiler](http://devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Compiler) to do the conversion:

```
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o devicetree.dts /path/to/devicetree.dtb
```

You can also attempt to find the source file used to make your device tree binary, but the only way to be certain you have the correct source is to use the compiler.

Comment: Surely it is the other way around?  You compile a text source to a binary (blob).

Comment: You can also de-compile it from a blob to a source file.

Comment: So you can, that would be useful if you cannot locate the source file.